# Hive subquery in rlike clause

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, weblog, bigdata

I want to clean robots entries from log file. One of the way to identify crawlers by the user agent field in weblog.I've stored raw logs in one folder and token of the popular crawlers in `crawler` table. TO clean logs those have user agent matched with token i made this query

```
CREATE TABLE temp 
AS
SELECT host,time,method,url,protocol,status,size,referer,agent 
FROM raw_logs
WHERE 
agent NOT RLIKE (SELECT concat_ws("|",collect_set(concat("(.*",token,".*)"))) FROM crawler) ;
```

It gives me parseException `cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'concat_ws' '(' in expression specification`

If i replace result of sub query manually then it works perfect.

```
CREATE TABLE temp 
AS
SELECT host,time,method,url,protocol,status,size,referer,agent 
FROM raw_logs
WHERE agent NOT RLIKE '(.*Googlebot.*)|(.*bingbot.*)'  ;
```

So sub query in `LIKE` clause not supported by hive 1.0.1 ?
Similar query in mysql works perfect.